# How to dock Skype4Business main window to parent application

Tags: c#, winforms, lync, skype-for-business, lync-client-sdk

I have requirements to glue skype4business (lync) to the side of parent application. Similar to below solution:
https://anywhere365.io/platform-element-inflight-snapper/

Answer (score 0):

There nothing in the Lync/SfB SDKs that will help you with this, so you'll have to look into other ways. One good option would be using Win32 calls - for example you could:

- Find the handle of the SfB client using `Process.GetProcessesByName("lync").FirstOrDefault().MainWindowHandle`
- Use this handle to set your form's `Owner` property (this will ensure your form behaves well e.g. minimizes when the SfB client minimizes)
- Set a timer to look for changes to the SfB client's size and position - you can read these using [GetWindowRect](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/getwindowrect.html)
- Update your form's size and position accordingly

Using the timer here is not optimal - it may be that you could wire up to events from the SfB client using other Win32 calls - e.g. something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15750038/detect-hook-window-move-drag-of-other-external-processes)